# No audio over USBC to HDMI on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound, hdmi, usb-c

I have a problem with audio using a USB-C to HDMI connection from my [Dell XPS15 7590](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-laptops-and-notebooks/xps-15-7590-laptop/spd/xps-15-7590-laptop/cax15wp1c1656p1) on Ubuntu 18.04. I have an ASUS VP28UQGL external monitor to which I am connecting my laptop and an Apple TV. The monitor has an audio output, so I connected my speakers to it in order to have audio for both devices easily through HDMI.

I tried 2 configurations:

- **Connecting my laptop to the screen using the HDMI output port of the laptop.** Here, the audio works great. However, whenever I lock my screen (I don't go to suspend), it turns off the monitors, and when I log back in, Ubuntu detects the external monitor, but the external monitor acts as if it has no input source (it displays *no source*). I have to plug out the HDMI cable, change sources or do some other things in order to get the monitor to detect the laptop.
- **Connecting my laptop to the screen using a USB-C to HDMI mini-dock (LMP 14368).** Here, I don't have any problems with the monitor. I lock my screen, and it unlocks without problems, on two screens. However, in this configuration, the audio over HDMI doesn't work. Or works sometimes, basically randomly.

So my question is, did anybody have a similar problem with the audio not working over a USB-C to HDMI mini-dock? And if yes, how was it solved?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem between my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop (Dell XPS 13) and Sharp Aquos TV. The HDMI output was not showing in the list of possible Sound outputs.

I solved it by restarting the laptop. The HDMI output option appeared and I was able to select it.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. I fixed it by using (installing it if needed)  `pavucontrol` and then correcting the audio player (i.e. Spotify) to run with the headphones.

Cheers,